# combobox undefined in document.ready

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, combobox, kendo-combobox

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var combobox = $("#Id").data("kendoComboBox");
 combobox.dataSource.data(jsonData);
});
```

I am trying to set the datasource for the combobox on document ready, but, i can't set the combobox is always undefined...

I am declaring combobox in razor partial view..

```
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Id)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;" })
         )
```

the comobo element is there...but the datasource for the combo is undefined..so may i need to init the datasource event on load? how can i do this?

Comment: it is a different scope.  If you move the set inside of the document ready where the var combobox is defined it should work for you

Comment: Are you sure that your combobox's id is `#combo`? Your Razor code will generate it with `#id`... And how do you load your partial with Ajax? Because in this case the DOM ready runs before your partial is loaded...

Comment: is the #combo element actually there?  Stick an alert($('#combo')[0]); in the first line of your doc ready to see if there's actually an element there.

Comment: the comobo element is there...but the datasource for the combo is undefined..so may i need to init the datasource event on load?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22726040/2001735

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript variables are scoped to a function. So you `var combobox` is only visible inside function you execute during `ready`. Fix move declaration and usage to the same scope:

```
$(function () { 
  var combobox = $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox");
  combobox.dataSource.data(jsonData);
});
```

or:

```
$(function () { });
var combobox = $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.dataSource.data(jsonData);
```

Note also that `.data("kendoComboBox")` may not be available yet if you run script before `ready`.

Comment: @WingMan20-10 - I assume you've looked at HTML and element with that ID exists, you've debugged the script (F12 in most browsers) and found that kendo is initialized *before* your call... Not sure what else - you may want to update your post with actions you've tried to debug the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo combobox is not included in the standard core or web packages.

Please use kendo.all.min.js located at
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js

in order to gain access to kendoComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var combobox = $("#ID").data("kendoComboBox");
 combobox.dataSource.read();
```