# KendoUI DateTimePicker undefined on document.ready

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a Kendo DateTimePicker control in an mvc (asp.net) partial view that I am trying to access from document.ready():

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(vvm => vvm.StartTime)
                    .Name("dtpVisitStart")
                    .Format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm tt")
                    .TimeFormat("HH:mm:tt")
                    .Events(e => e.Change("dtpVisitStart_Change")
                                )                               
)
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    TestDTP();
});

function TestDTP() {
    var dtp = $("#dtpVisitStart").getKendoDateTimePicker();
    debugger;
}
```

When the debugger line runs dtp is undefined. How can I initialize this date time picker when the partial view loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is initializing the datetimepicker from pure javascript and ditched the razor version:

```
function TestDTP() {
    $("#dtpVisitStart").kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm", 
        change: dtpVisitStart_Change, 
        value: "@(startTime)"
    });
    var dtp = $("#dtpVisitStart").getKendoDateTimePicker();
    debugger;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your original approach should work if you put the ready block at the bottom of the page, or at least below the widget initialization code ([also see this section of the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#client-side-object)).

If you put it above the `@(Html.Kendo()` section, `TestDTP` will run before the widget is initialized, since the widget initialization code is also wrapped in a jQuery ready block (and the various ready blocks are executed sequentially).

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this to get the instance:

var dtp = $('#dtpVisitStart').data('kendoDateTimePicker');

Comment: I *believe* the way I am getting it and the way you are is basically the same. My code works as is outside of the document.ready but no from within.